# Image resizing + hosting (language independent)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3, image, resize, resize-image

For several of my applications (MVC3 / RoR / PHP) I am looking for a library (framework or as a service) to resize images on the fly + host the different sizes on a CDN / cache somewhere not to use my own bandwidth.

Bonus : It should work on mobile too to generate thumbnails + store them on a cache somewhere (S3 or Rackspace, whatever).

Thank you very much in advance for your replies.

Cheers

Comment: Imagemagick + store resized images on S3?

Comment: Cloudfront for your CDN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My company launched a service like this : cloudimage.io, but a few others exists too:

- http://cloudimage.io
- http://cloudinary.com
- http://imageresizing.net
- http://imgix.com

For cloudimage.io, if you have an image such as http://mywebsite.com/photo.jpg, you can simply resize it at 400px for mobile like this : http://cloudimage.io/t/resize/400/mywebsite.com/photo.jpg.

Then the mobile will download the images directly in the right size. On a mobile application, if your app is used worldwide, having your images stored on a worldwide CDN is usually better for the user experience.

You'll find a lot of examples on the above websites.

Comment: Since Flo wants to use this in his application, does any of these services provide a web API which he could use?

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, you can use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) or PaperClip.
You can specify the external CDN (such as Amazon EC2) to store the cached and generated images.

`CarrierWave` allows you high flexibility, ranging from dynamic generation of thumbnails (as specified by you; courtesy `RMagick` - Ruby ImageMagick impelmentation), size constraints, extension blacklisting and so on.

Hope it serves your purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much, however I would like to have a service that is language independant as I will use it with different projects in different languages. I checked PaperClip, it seems great.

Comment: Great. Check out [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/features#development_frameworks) definitely then.